# How to pass additional data to the post_ajax method?

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-views, dropzone.js

I have the models:

```
class MyModelOne(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Title'), max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Body'))
    # some other fields


class MyModelTwo(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Title'), max_length=255)
    # some other fields


class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Title'), max_length=255)
    image = StdImageField(verbose_name=_('Image'),upload_to='photos')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I want to include a dropzone (DropzoneJS) field for creating Photos objects inside the admin change views of some other models while updating their objects. I am using the ajax view to handle it independently to the admin change view form.

To create the Photo object I need to pass the other model currently updated object's data to the post_ajax method.

I don't know how to recognize the current object model and its id in the post_ajax method, where I want to handle the Photos creating.

```
from braces.views import AjaxResponseMixin, JSONResponseMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, SuperuserRequiredMixin

class AjaxPhotoUploadView(
    LoginRequiredMixin,
    SuperuserRequiredMixin,
    JSONResponseMixin,
    AjaxResponseMixin,
    View,
):
    def post_ajax(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file = request.FILES['file']
        obj = ??? # I need to get the object somewhere here but I do not know how
        Photo.objects.create(
            title=file.name,
            image=file,
            content_object=obj, 
        )
        response_dict = {
            'message': 'File uploaded successfully!',
        }
        return self.render_json_response(response_dict, status=200)
```

Comment: Have you checked the content of request.POST in your view?

Comment: Yes. The http_referer url from request META (`/admin/mymodels/mymodelone/1234/change/#media' for example) looks the most helpful but I am not sure if this would be a good solution to pull the data out of the url.

Comment: In your code, where does the variable `obj` come from?

Comment: Oops. The problem is I don't know where should I get this variable value from.

Comment: Well you could send the `obj` id and model name in the ajax request, by the way, can we see it?

Comment: I have no direct access to modify the ajax code. I use the DropzoneJS library and I just pass the URL to it like this: $(".fallback").dropzone({url: {% url "ajax_photo_upload_view" %}});